# Format text in auto email script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I use the following script to send auto confirmations from a spreadsheet which is synced with a google form.

```js
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values[2];
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
                    "Thanks for Volunteering",
                     " Hello\n\n"+
                     "Thanks you\n\n"+
                     "Have a great day\n\n",
                     {name:"ABC"});
                             }​
```

The `\n` takes the text to the next line. However, it's all left aligned. Is there anything I can add to make it right aligned? something like `\r`?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The text body of an email supports no formatting. You could embed tabs (`\t`) or spaces to try to push the text to the right; but how would you know how wide the recipient's display is?

If you want to control the presentation of your email, you need to use the `htmlBody` option [described here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29).

You can affect basic formatting with embedded css styles, by wrapping the text of the email in `<div>` tags, and placing css property / value pairs in a `style` attribute. For example, this would produce right-aligned text (go ahead, "run" it and see):

```html
<div style='text-align:right'>
  This is the text <br> that we want to have <br> right-aligned.
</div>
```

This example wraps the text version of the email body in `<div>` tags with our selected style, replacing the newline characters to html `<br>` tags. When we send this email, both the text and html versions are included; recipients with email clients that support html will see the right-aligned html version, others will see the plain text.

```js
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values[2];
  var text = "Hello\n\n"+
             "Thanks you\n\n"+
             "Have a great day\n\n";
  var html = "<div style='text-align:right'>"
           + text.replace(/\\n/g,"<br>")   // Replace newlines with breaks
           + "</div>"
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
                    "Thanks for Volunteering",
                    text,
                    { name: "ABC"
                      htmlBody: html });
}​
```