# Can I set MailApp.sendEmail text to align to the right with out using htmlbody

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I want to get Hebrew text from  a google doc  and send it by email using google script, can i get the email text to be aligned to the right with out using `htmlbody` in the `mailApp.sendEmail`

```
var doc =DocumentApp.openById("...")
var message = doc.getText();
```

the text should be sent by mail like so:

```
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

can i get the text in the message to be aligned to the right with out using htmlbody?

Comment: see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050046/format-text-in-auto-email-script

Comment: @Sergeinsas thanks, I was hoping that there is an option to copy the formating from the doc so i dont need to ude htmlbody

Comment: Are you just concerned about right-alignment? Hebrew is read right-to-left, isn't it? Is that a factor in this problem? It would be really helpful if you could provide a [mcve], and explain how it's not quite what you need.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the recipients settings? If I open a text file with Hebrew Unicode text it will align left until I tell it to align right. Without html you cannot change the users layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no setting that can be done for the MailApp namespace of AppScript. You can set the text direction using [Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph), however, it seems to only be for some Google products like Docs (DocumentApp).